# How to properly use edit text change listener in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How to properly use edit text change listener android? I know that it sounds a little bit easy for some of you guys but I am stuck with this problem. I used to edit text change listener regarding my search feature in my app. then I used a filter for it to filter depending on the user is typing. for example the user type ka and karl, kamille will be suggested into the list. and first of all I set the recyclerview visibility to false so that in the start up the recyclerview wont be visible and it will only be visible if the edittext is not null or should I say the user is already typing. I already did that if the user type any single character the recyclerview will become visible but after that it just stay the same. I want if the edit text is null the recyclerview will become invisible again.

Here's my code in my app regarding edit text change listener.

```
   searchusersedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
      count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
      int count) {
                       }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(searchusersedittext!=null) {
                recyclerViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                filter(s.toString());
            }
            else if(searchusersedittext.equals("")){
                recyclerViews.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else if(searchusersedittext==null){
                recyclerViews.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                recyclerViews.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }




        }
    });
```

Isn't correct? or did i miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stays visible because `searchusersedittext` is always non-null in that call (if it were null, the earlier call to `searchusersedittext.addTextChangedListener` would fail with a `NullPointerException`), so once you type anything at all it only goes into the first case every time (keeping it visible).

Also `searchusersedittext.equals("")` isn't checking for an empty entry in the EditText, since `searchusersedittext` is an EditText object, not the entered string. The EditText object continues to exist, even if there is no text entered in it.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String txt = searchusersedittext.getText().toString();
    // or String txt = s.toString();
    if( !txt.isEmpty() ) {
        recyclerViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        filter(txt);
    }
    else {
        recyclerViews.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like promising. ill definitely try this one. anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private Timer timer;

    TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               // do your actual work here
            }
        }, 600); 
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }};
```